# Open data sources similar to the Workplace and Employee Survey (WES)

Tags: data-request, business, big-data

I've read some interesting analysis papers based on the Workplace and Employee Survey (WES), however it seems the data for this survey is not open to the public: http://www.rdc-cdr.ca/datasets/wes-workplace-and-employee-survey

Does anyone know of similar sources with datasets?